# дубликаты при ответе с сервера, express js, sequelize.query,

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

решил написать запрос, так как подумал, что так легче

Вот кусок кода

```
const counts = await sequelize.query(
  `SELECT
                count(if(status='in progress', 1, NULL)) AS 'inProgressCounts',
                count(if(status='closed', 1, NULL)) AS 'closedCounts',
                count(if(status='frozen', 1, NULL)) AS 'frozenCounts'
            FROM tasks, usertasks 
            WHERE tasks.id=usertasks.taskId AND usertasks.userId=${req.user.id}`
)
return res.json(counts);
```

В phpMyAdmin все нормально, но когда я отправляю запрос через постман у меня приходит ответ с дубликатами
[image: Ответ в постмане]

Answer (score 0):

Решил. Я просто не знал как работает sequelize.query
ДО

```
const counts = await sequelize.query('...')
```

ПОСЛЕ

```
const [results, metadata] = await sequelize.query('...')
return res.json(results);
```